# How can I securely store user credentials for my app

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-authentication, basic-authentication, auth0

I have an Android app that allows users to interact with a third-party service via their API. This API makes use of Basic Authentication, so I need the user's username and password for every API call. Ideally I don't want to store the user's credentials locally as this is very insecure. I don't know much about authentication but this is what I think my ideal solution would be:

- The user provides their credentials to this service once for verification
- Once verified, I send the user's credentials to a backend service to store them, which gives me an auth token. I store this token locally (is encryption important here?)
- Whenever I want to make future calls to this service, I use this auth token to talk to the backend service, which provides me with the user's username/password for Basic Authentication to make API calls

Is this a good solution? If so, are there backend services in place that I can use to facilitate this process? I've looked at Firebase Authentication but I don't know if it fills my needs as I'm trying to store credentials for a third-party service, not specifically for my app. I've heard of Auth0 which may be what I'm looking for but appears to be overkill for a small app like mine.

Comment: have you looked at firebase or even parse-server?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Firebase Auth and get all the functionality you need while keeping your users secure. It provides the features you need:

1. Firebase supports password authentication and properly stores hashed/salted password credentials according the industry standards. This would be one API to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` or `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.
2. Firebase provides a mechanism to verify email addresses. It is also one API: `user.sendEmailVerification()`
3. On sign in, Firebase Auth returns an ID token (`user.getIdToken()`) which you can use to identify your users in all authenticated requests. They also provide an Admin SDK to parse and verify that token (`auth.verifyIdToken(idToken)`). A refresh token is also provided to continuously refresh ID tokens on expiration. This means the sessions are indefinite and the user should not need to sign in again on the device.
4. The ID token provides additional user data like `email_verified` which you can use to ensure the user is verified. The ID token is a JWT which can't be compromised without the Firebase Auth backend private key.

Comment: How will this work if the credentials are username/password, not email/password?

Comment: Hmm, I missed that part. If you want to send an email verification, then you will need to require the email on registration. You just need a mapping: username <=> email. You can use Firebase real-time database to store that mapping. So when a user signs in after account creation, they provide the username and pass. You get the corresponding email and `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. This may require some work but it is a lot easier/safer than storing email/pass credentials on your own.